# Designing a neural network for decision making depending on 50 factors

Tags: artificial-intelligence, neural-network, expert-system, encog

I am building a back-propagation neural network (with Encog library) that makes decisions depending on about 50 factor, I want help with its best design : We need 50 input neuron for sure, and 4 neurons as output to give the answer ( 4 digits) but I am not sure about the number of neurons in the hidden layer, how many is the best?
also I want to ask if back-propagation with segmoid activation function is the best for this kind of situations. 
Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a single hidden layer.  A neural network with only one hidden layer has been shown to be a universal approximation. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_approximation_theorem

As to the number of hidden neurons.  You will need to experiment.  I would start with 50, and try 25-75.

Sigmoid is fine, if your expected output is between 0 and 1.  You can also try tanh if you normalize to -1 to 1.